# A program that creates a fake ftp server

Tags: c++, python, perl

I would like guidance on how to write a fake ftp server that does not allow upload but will record the attempt of users trying to connect to it and write it in a file in either python, c++ or perl. Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Google for "ftp honeypot".

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you try to build an FTP honeypot, so what about looking at already existing FTP honeypot solutions?

Otherwise, read [RFC959](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc959.txt) and look in the module directories of various languages for FTP modules which you could use to implement the desired functionality:

- [Perl - CPAN](http://metacpan.org)
- [Python - PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi)
- [Ruby - RubyGems](http://rubygems.org/)
- [Go](http://golang.org/pkg/)

If you're looking for a Perl based solution, the module [Net::FTPServer](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aFTPServer) looks like a good base to start…